# How to add more than one string in rust arrays?

Tags: rust

This is the code which i want tried to write but get  error in solving it i am beginner in  rust dont know so much Will be great if some one guide me

```
fn main(){

  let list = ["PAKISTAN","INDIA","IRAN","CHINA","TURKEY"};

  let list1 = [2,3,4,5,6];

  print!("Fourth Index {} \n\n\n\n",list[4],"/t/t:{}",list1[1]);

}
```

Comment: There are several small errors which would have been avoided by testing the code before asking. If you can't do it locally you can always use a playground like https://play.rust-lang.org/

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `print!` should be the full string that you want to print. It seems like you probably want this:

```
print!("Fourth Index {} \n\n\n\n\t\t:{}", list[4], list1[1]);
```

Two other quick notes:

1. `"TURKEY"};` should be `"TURKEY"];` with `]` instead of `}`.
2. As in the line above, you have `/t` when I assume you meant `\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, after @loganfsmyth's improvements will print:

- element at index `4` from `list`,
- element at index `2` from `list1`.

I wonder if you wanted to print:

- element at index `4` from `list`,
- element at index `4` from `list1`.

If this is the case, the risk of using two different indexes can be reduced by, instead of two, having a single list of [tuples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.tuple.html).

The tuple-ed version of the code could be as the following.

```
let list = [("PAKISTAN",2),("INDIA",3),("IRAN",4),("CHINA",5),("TURKEY",6)];

let i = 4;
print!("Fifth Element {} \n\n\n\n\t\t:{}",list[i].0, list[i].1);
```

*Please note that `list[4]` is the **Fift** index, not the **Forth**.*

---

### Note on alignment

With `\t\t` the code seems to align the country with the number. The `t` technique doesn't work well with strings of different widths. Fortunately Rust comes with padding and alignment options for formatting strings.

Let's showcase how this could be used for your example.

```
let list = [("PAKISTAN",2),("INDIA",3),("IRAN",4),("CHINA",5),("TURKEY",6)];

let i = 4;
let score = format!(":{}",list[i].1);  //This gives us ':6'

//>30 = right alignment, width of 30   
print!("Fifth Element\n{:>30}\n\n\n\n{:>30}",list[i].0, score);
```

#### Output

```
Fifth Element
                        TURKEY



                            :6
```

*Please note that this only works for [fixed width fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).*